# How to find highest combination in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that has repeating values in 2 columns and I only want to keep the highest value of each combination. For the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
np.array([['A', 'B ', 3], ['A', 'B', 6], ['C', 'D', 9],  ['C', 'D', 2], ['C', 'B', 4]]))
df
```

how would I get this dataframe as a result:

```
|A|B|6|
|C|D|9|
|C|B|4|
```

Comment: you have a space in the first row `'B '` . Is that intended?

Comment: that is a mistake.

Comment: ```df.groupby([0,1]).max().sort_values(2,ascending=False)``` variant

Comment: Use `df.groupby([0,1], sort=False, as_index=False).max()`

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` and `aggregate` max:

```
df.groupby([0,1], as_index=False)[2].max()
```

Here's a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44776593/group-by-two-columns-and-max-value-of-third-in-pandas-python) with a similar use case.

Comment: while that does show the numbers, I would also like it to show the 2 columns that have the letters. Can you please fix the code and I'll deem this answer as correct.

Comment: when I use this command, I get a three columned DataFrame with two columns containing letters and one column with the numbers. Could you describe the output of your code? Is yours resulting in a Series? Or a single columned DataFrame?