# How to get highest number from row combination

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that has repeating values in 2 columns and I only want to keep the highest value of each combination. For the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
np.array([['A', 'B ', 3], ['A', 'B', 6], ['C', 'D', 9],  ['C', 'D', 2], ['C', 'B', 4]]))
df
```

how would I get this dataframe as a result:

```
|A|B|6|
|C|D|9|
|C|B|4|
```

Here's my code:

```
df = df.groupby([0]).max().sort_values(2,ascending=False)
df
```

and this is what it returns:

```
|A|B|6|
|C|D|9|
```

My problem with my code is that it only sorts the values on the first column (so CB is the same as CB, but I want 2 separate values returned). I only want to keep the highest row for all combinations. Some posts very similar but different is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705630/get-the-rows-which-have-the-max-value-in-groups-using-groupby). Can someone please let me know what I can do to fix this problem? Thanks!

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61721971/how-to-find-highest-combination-in-dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
In [131]: df.groupby([0, 1], as_index=False, sort=False).max()                                                                                                                                              
Out[131]: 
   0  1  2
0  A  B  6
1  C  D  9
2  C  B  4
```

Comment: To get the correct order `df.groupby([0, 1], as_index=False, sort=False).max()`

Comment: In your code you are grouping on only `[0]`. But you need to group on the combination of `[0]` and `[1]`. Then take the max of column `[2]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
df.sort_values(2).drop_duplicates([0,1], keep='last')
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2
4  C  B  4
1  A  B  6
2  C  D  9
```

Comment: when I tried it in my code, there were still 2 rows that had the AB combination

Comment: @UserX then there is something different about your data from what you provided.